# Button enabled or disabled : How does webdriver decide?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How does selenium webdriver decide whether a button is enabled or disabled? I have used the    isEnabled() 
method for two buttons - one enabled and the other disabled but it returns true for both the cases. Is there a workaround other than using isEnabled() ?

Comment: Can you check for the attribute `disabled` in the two button(s). I am guessing it is not present for the one you're mentioning is disabled. Hence, you are getting the output as enabled for both. Furthermore, can you please also tell, how are you determining that the button is disabled ?

Comment: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webdriver/raw-file/default/webdriver-spec.html#widl-WebElement-isEnabled-boolean

Comment: Disabled button has the attribute disabled in its class property whereas the enabled one doesn't have it. I am checking the output of isEnabled to determine if the button is enabled/ disabled.

Comment: So what's the markup of the enabled vs the disabled one?

Answer (score 8):

isEnabled() checks for the [disabled *attribute* on the button element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp). If the attribute "disabled" is not present, it returns True, so if you never add this attribute to disabled buttons and instead add the value "disabled" to the button's class, isEnabled() will always return true.

If you are determining whether the button is enabled or disabled based on a class, you will need to instead check for the existence of a button with the "disabled" class (find it by class name, xpath, or CSS selector) to decide what state the button is in.

Answer (score 2):

`isEnabled()` is a good answer, but it has recently been updated to just `Enabled`, as a getter on the `IWebElement`.

Example:

```
Driver.findElement(By.Class("example-class-name")).Enabled
```