# isEnabled() function in selenium always returns true, when webdriver is running on sites developed using Angular 6

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, angular6, selenium-chromedriver, isenabled

The isEnabled() function in selenium webdriver returns true always, when the webdriver is running on sites developed using Angular 6. All the answers relating to this topic that I found talked about the disabled not being an attribute and instead being written in the class of the button. Check this link for a detailed description.

[Button enabled or disabled : How does webdriver decide?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27293038)

But the code of the website that I am working on does not have it written in the class. Here is the code of my website.

```
<button _ngcontent-c61="" class="push-right-sm mat-raised-button mat-primary" color="primary" mat-raised-button="" disabled="">
<span class="mat-button-wrapper">SAVE</span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
```

How should I check if this element is enabled or not correctly?

Edit: Here is how I check it through my code.

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/span[contains(text(),'SAVE')]"));
if(button.isEnabled()){ System.out.println("The button is enabled."); }
```

Comment: Post the code you are using to check enabled.

Comment: Hi @JeffC I've added the code that I use in the question. Please check and do reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locator is finding the `SPAN` inside the `BUTTON` and not the button itself. Try

```
//button[./span[.='SAVE']]
```

NOTE: You don't need to use `contains()` in this case since the entirety of the text is "SAVE" so I removed `contains()`.

This basically reads as find a `BUTTON` that has a `SPAN` that has contained text equal to "SAVE". I tested it on the HTML you provided and it's working.